# How to seperate a list of items in php?

Tags: php

I have a list of 100 emails which I am trying to save to a database.

I can obtain the data in the page that it sends to via

the PHP $_POST variable but it stores all the data as one single item how do I separate this data so I can use it in a for loop on each item in the list so that I can save it into a database?

Comment: Give us your code sample and what you have tried!

Comment: Do you have an example of the data?

Comment: it's just a list of random emails... I don't have any code samples not sure if it is possible?

Comment: @MatthewduPlessis paste here whatever you are getting in $_POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your emails are separated by a space or comma:
you want the php function [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
and then foreach over the resulting array.

Or perhaps [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)?
$emails = preg_split('/[\s;,]+/', $string_o_emails)